# Working with Cakephp SessionId

Tags: cakephp

I'm studying CakePHP and I have this question :

- Why I dont see the Session ID in Cookie when I use Firebug ?
- How can I force CakePHP to use a session ID ?

Pls help me out :D

Edit :

What I mean is :

Exp : in controller I user `$this->Session->write(....);`

As I know that will start the `session()` but when I use Firebug I don't see the `SESSIONID`.

My question is where is the `SESSIONID` in `cakephp` ?

I tried to `session_start()` in view but will get error that : `"session already start".`

Comment: Without additional information, I don't think you'll get an answer here. Please include 'what you tried', add relevant code. Read the [faq].

Comment: Thank you for adding the extra information

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for a `PHPSESSID` cookie but it isn't mandatory to give that name to the session cookie. It's very easy to [change it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) and CakePHP indeed does it. You can also [configure your own cookie name](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html) right in CakePHP.

Finally, don't use `session_start()` yourself. You are building an app on top a high-level framework that already takes care of such stuff.

Comment: When I view cookie by firebug there is only CAKEPHP with value myownsessionid,it this the PHPSESSID I am looking for ?

Comment: @DucAnh - Yes, it is.

Comment: Tks ! Another question,can the browser automatically change the session id when session id is sent in url.I meant,like example of Session fixtaion ?

Comment: I have the impression that it just uses your server's default settings (which you can change via `Session.ini`).